# Form Validation from service.ts Angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, static-methods, angular-services

I need to add custom validators to a form from formvalidation.service.ts 
form.component.ts

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required,]]
});
```

formvalidator.service.ts

```
passwordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
   return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]:any} | null => {
     const year = control.value;
     if (!/[0-9]/.test(year) || !/[A-Z]/.test(year)) {
       return { passwordPattern: true};
     }
     return null;
   }
}
```

I import it as  `FormValidator.passwordValidator()`. It can't import this to the component.ts file.
But when the `static passwordValidator(): ValidatorFn {}` it can do. but my superviser advice me to not to use static methods.

Comment: That's because if you create your function inside a class, if you want to call it you have to instance the class: `new FormValidator().passwordValidator()`. For me it's overkill creating a class only for this, it's probably better to create a standalone function and export it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need service class instance in form.component:

```
export class FormComponent {
  ...
  constructor(private validator: FormValidatorService) {}
  myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, this.validator.passwordValidator]]
  });
  ...
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not import as FormValidator.passwrodValidator, but you can inject the service in the constructor of your component and use

```
constructor(private formValidator:FormValidator){}
//and use
name:['',this.formValidator.passwordValidator]
```

The another option is declare the function outside the service (but in the same .ts)

```
export function passwordValidator(): ValidatorFn {..}
```

Then you can `import {passwordValidator} from './services/service.ts'`